# LWUIT HtmlComponent Lines don't get wrapped + Parser Problem

Tags: xhtml, java-me, lwuit

I think I'm facing a simple layout problem.
I'm embedding a `HTMLComponent` on a Form via LWUIT, this `HTMLComponent`
displays a local HTML file. The result has no line wrapping but endless
scrolling in X direction.

How can I change this behaviour?

I also have some tags in the files which aren't really supported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><doc><head><title>
```

How can I still parse the files, without removing those tags manually?
Do I need to modify my `DocumentRequestHandler` or where can I do that?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

For the line warpping, please check if any specific "width" is defined in you local HTML (or CSS) file. For example, if the width is given as "600" pixels and the screen is less than "600" then scrolling may appear. So either remove the specific width or change it to "100%".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this isn't the case. It even happens with a plain file containing just:

`<html><body>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</body></html>`

Comment: Try adding a few spaces in your text, so "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" should be something like "AAAA AA AAA AAAAA". I assume this is your testing string, since it is way long the rendering component will never wrap it unless there is word boundaries just like in normal language no work is that long.

Comment: This was just an example - I need to display several hundred HTML files, so editing them manually is not possible.

Comment: But even if I add spaces it's not wrapping - which is the problem.